# Textures black after importing obj file

Tags: rendering

I've been having this issue for a good day or two. Whenever I import obj files to blender the textures are black. The version of blender I'm currently using is v2.74. I was wondering if someone could assist me on this because I'm trying to finish something for Garry's Mod.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: OBJ doesn't import materials, you are supposed to manually create them yourself

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos this is not a dup of that one, nor is it the same issue. Look at the properties panel he has the texture in the material. The OP's problem here is there are no light in the 3D view to illuminate the object.

Comment: Hadn't noticed, good catch

Comment: @David♦ Thank you so much for your help! This worked for me big time!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a light to see (if everything is dark you can only see black).

You simply imported the mesh, there is nothing else in your scene. You have no lights in your scene. You (kind of) need a light to see your object.

For just a simple test render, or so you can see your object, just add a few lamps. If you add just one then the side in the shadow will still be black.